# When is it necessary to pass object as argument in a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object

if I don't want to use 'this' as an object and directly write the function without passing 'this' as an object and directly write this.src="" in the function why would that not work??

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function picture(yolo){
    yolo.src="3Nail.jpg";
  }

  function normal(yolo) {
    yolo.src="4Nail.jpg";
  }
</script>

 <img onmouseover="picture(this)" onmouseout="normal(this)" src="1nail.jpg" alt="n1"/>
<img onmouseover="picture(this)" onmouseout="normal(this)" src="2nail.jpg" alt="n2"/>
```

Comment: Show us how you are calling these functions.

Comment: The `this` keyword just means something different when it's in a different scope. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey,  am calling these functions using onmouseover event handler

Comment: So, is it that we cant use 'this' directly in a function??

Comment: Well, you can use it, but it doesn't refer to the same thing as `this` in the event handler. Check out the [MDN docs on the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 2):

As the functions are not associated with event handlers, their `this` references the global window object. In order to avoid having to use the variable `yolo` as an argument, you can supply the this binding to the functions by calling them with this as the context using `call` as shown below.

js

```
  function picture(){
    this.src="3Nail.jpg";
  }

  function normal() {
    this.src="4Nail.jpg";
  }
```

html

```
<img onmouseover="picture.call(this)" onmouseout="normal.call(this)" src="1nail.jpg" alt="n1"/>
<img onmouseover="picture.call(this)" onmouseout="normal.call(this)" src="2nail.jpg" alt="n2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! .call is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `img` tag, `this` refers to that specific `img` element. Here, inside the function, `this` would be `window`. In general, the `this` inside a function refers to the object the function belongs to.

Thus, if you were to call the function without passing that element from the `img` tag, the function would have no way of knowing which element it should update. Of course, you can use query selectors inside the function to grab what you need -- but that only works if you always want to update the same element(s).